# How can I let a parent element behave exactly like its child in terms of size?

Tags: javascript, html, css

For example, if I place

```
<div>
    <img ...>
</div>
```

somewhere and then apply the styles `width`, `height`, `max-width`, etc. to the `div` element, I want the result to look exactly as if I had placed the `img` element there and applied the styles to it.

Is this possible using CSS? If not, is it possible using JavaScript?

Edit: For clarification. I'm not looking for a solution to a specific case. Rather, I'm looking for some sort of pattern to replace `img` elements with `div > img` elements, without changing the look. The pattern should work in as many contexts as possible.

Comment: `inline-block` on parent and height:100% width:100% on image and pay attention to white space ... and what is this syntax `<img ...></img>` ?

Answer (score 1):

You could simply use

```
img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: block;
}
```

However, this will most likely result in a distorted image (i.e. width to height proportion), except if you define width and height exactly in the proportion to each other which corresponds to the image proportions.

Comment: i would add vertical-align:top to image to remove the white space

Comment: @TemaniAfif This would help if the image is an inline-block, but not per default (where image is an inline element). But thanks for bringing this up, I forgot about it. Now I added `display: block;` to prevent what you describe.

Comment: not the downvoter by the way :) well +1 to revert it

Comment: @TheOneWhoMade the OP want the image to fit the div and this answer is at the moment the more appropriate one

Comment: This works well in many cases but not in all of them (as already mentioned). An example where it doesn't work: https://jsfiddle.net/owhm3qkr/ Both images should look the same despite `max-height` and `max-width` applied to the elements of `#mainContainer`.

Comment: In that jsfiddle you are mixing inline styles with CSS rules in a style tag without considering how those styles work together, and due to that the CSS is NOT the same. Look at this version where I corrected that (adding the styles from `#imageContainer > img`  to the inline styles of the first image) and where both images look the same: https://jsfiddle.net/mpv7mndo/1/

Comment: I am looking for a pattern that allows me to replace `img` elements with `div > img` elements. If you look at it that way, the look of the second image in the fiddle would have to be adjusted to look like the first one. (In yours, it's the other way around.) Of course, it wouldn't be a problem to find a solution in this particular fiddle. But I am looking for one that works in as many contexts as possible.

Comment: The inline styles where just to simulate one specific context where the pattern should work.

Comment: what I mean is: If you merge the CSS from the style tag and the inline styles, the two elements in your fiddle do NOT have the same styles, whereas in my fiddle, they do

Comment: Hm, I don't see that. In my example the two outer elements (first `img` and second `div`) have `max-width` and `max-height` specified, nothing else. Even after merging. I verified that using devtools. Then I added `width` and `height` and `display` to the second `img` because that was your proposed solution to make it look like the first. Note: I actually made a typo and forgot `max-width:` on the first `img` but I tested it and it doesn't change anything.

Comment: One could say that this is the given baseline https://jsfiddle.net/zpeLk9bp/. The task is to make the second picture look like the first one. Therefore I applied your solution and got https://jsfiddle.net/aw8z7nx9/.

Answer (score 0):

Set the css property `display` to `inline-block`.

Here is a snippet (div border is in blue):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style> 
#example1 {
    box-sizing: content-box;    
    display:inline-block;
}

</style>
</head>
<body>

<h1>


<p></p>
<div id="example1"><img src="https://lh4.googleusercontent.com/-Y6mZ3dizRWA/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAZ8/lC8SUn_bjkU/photo.jpg?sz=48"></img></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `margin-bottom:-18px` ? and if the OP use wrong tag you must at least correct them

Comment: it's called whitespace not *browser shifting* and this a hack not a fix :)

Comment: add overflow:hidden to the div and see what happen ;) then you will understand

Answer (score -1):

Yes, if you set `width: 100%` and `height: 100%` to your image it will take the size of your div.

But your image will be stretch that way, you may only want to specify its width or height or if you want a smart way to fill a div with an image prefer a `background-image` with a `background-size` to `cover` or `contain`.

PS: A image tag is a unique tag : `<img>` not `<img></img>`

Comment: there is no `/` and the end of image tag. And why `position:relative` ?

Comment: Exact, there is no `/` I did not knew that. And yes `position: relative` is not usefull there, but it's need when the child have a position absolute or fixed, the size of parent isn't taken into consideration.

Comment: The reason why the answers I have received so far are not suitable for me is that I am looking for a general solution. So to say, a pattern to replace `img` elements with `img` in `div` elements. Finding a solution for a special case isn't the problem. By the way, the downvotes aren't from me.